# Unexpected result converting list to array

Tags: c#, arrays, date

The below code outputs "February,February,February,February, February"

However I am trying to output the last 6 months on a rolling basis - can anyone help?

Thanks!

```
      DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);//The AddDays function is self explanatory although you can have negative numbers in here

          DateTime StartDate = EndDate.AddMonths(-1); //When do you want the meetings to start DateTime.Today will return midnight
          DateTime m = StartDate.AddMonths(-6);

          List<months> monthstore = new List<months>();

          months monthdata = new months();

          while (m < StartDate)
          {
              monthdata.month = m.ToString("MMMM");
              monthstore.Add(monthdata);

              m = m.AddMonths(1);
          }
        var publicationTable = new[] {
    new[] { monthstore.Select(x=> x.month).ToArray()  }

};
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the structure of `months`?

Comment: @SonerGönül does it really matter? As long it is not `struct` (I seriously doubt it would be) outcome is always the same - single object added many times to list.

Answer (score 3):

put

```
 months monthdata = new months();
```

into the loop, you are changing always the same object. `months` is a reference type